# Is it possible to have two package management systems (.deb and .rpm) on one system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.10, package-management, rpm, deb

Is it possible to have more than one package management system on one system?

Example: RPM, deb and .txz on the same partition of Ubuntu.

If it isn't possible, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. For example, Debian includes `yum` and `rpm` in its standard repositories. Also, many programming languages have their own package management tools, used only for installing modules for that particular language – for example, I have Perl `cpanm`, Ruby `gem`, Haskell `cabal` and Python `pip` in addition to the system-wide package manager.

However, using two package managers system-wide – e.g. `dpkg` and `rpm` – will cause problems *very* quickly; primarily due to file conflicts when manager A attempts to install a program that has already been installed by manager B.

Also, different distributions have different packaging policies. `deb` packages are usually built for Debian, while `rpm` is primarily used by Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS, and they use different initscripts, configuration files, and program data locations. Packages using `/etc/sysconfig` will break on mainly-`deb` systems.

Comment: I understand it alot better now :D